# why there is an error about char array printf error?

Tags: c

// in "instrct_content" array , only **"main", "lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4" and "lab5"** strings will be stored.

```
char** instrct_content = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)); 

while(scanf("%s", str) != EOF){ 
    if (strrchr(str, ':') != NULL){
        instrct_content = (char**)realloc(instrct_content, sizeof(char));
        instrct_content[instrct_cnt] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        instrct_content[instrct_cnt] = strcpy(instrct_content[instrct_cnt], str);
        printf("%s ", instrct_content[instrct_cnt]); // (1)
        instrct_cnt +=1;
            
  }

for (int i=0; i<instrct_cnt; i++){ 
    printf("%s ", instrct_content[i]); // (2) 
}
```

in (1) printf, the correct strings are printed (i.e. main: lab1: lab2: lab3: lab4: lab5: ), but in (2) printf, ( i.e. �g`M �g`M lab2: lab3: lab4: lab5: ) are printed. The strange words are printed. But I don't know why ...

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates memory for a *single* character. Even for a one-character string you need space for two, to also fit the string null-terminator. So your very next statement will write *out of bounds* of your allocated memory, and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And both the initial `malloc` call as well as the `realloc` call are wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

The presented code doe not make sense.

At least in this statement

```
instrct_content = (char**)realloc(instrct_content, sizeof(char));
```

you have to use expression `sizeof( char * )` instead of `sizeof( char )`.

It seems you mean something like the following.

```
size_t instrct_cnt = 0;
char **instrct_content = NULL; 

while ( scanf("%s", str) != EOF )
{
    if ( strrchr( str, ':' ) != NULL )
    {
        instrct_content = realloc( instrct_cnt + 1, sizeof( char * ) );
        instrct_content[instrct_cnt] = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 );
        strcpy( instrct_content[instrct_cnt], str ); 
        printf("%s ", instrct_content[instrct_cnt]); // (1)
        ++instrct_cnt;
    }
}
```

Or

```
size_t instrct_cnt = 0;
char **instrct_content = NULL; 

while ( scanf("%s", str) != EOF )
{
    char *p = strrchr( str, ':' ) )
    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        instrct_content = realloc( instrct_cnt + 1, sizeof( char * ) );
        instrct_content[instrct_cnt] = malloc( strlen( p + 1 ) + 1 );
        strcpy( instrct_content[instrct_cnt], p + 1 ); 
        printf("%s ", instrct_content[instrct_cnt]); // (1)
        ++instrct_cnt;
    }
}
```